# Unwanted space when Echoing a value

Tags: php

I want a comment to appear under a cell, whenever the `$comment` value exists.

Therefore I came with the following code:

```
$comment = "Enabled";  // add comment, whenever this value is not set to "0"

            <td>
              <form action="go.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
              <input type="submit" class="a" value="click"></form>
              <?= !$comment ? "" : "<div class=\"design\">Comment: " . $comment;"</div>" ?>
            </td>
```

But in the output, I get unwanted space after `Enabled` which looks like:

```
<div class="design">Comment: Enabled            </div>
```

What causes this?

Comment: The whitespace shouldn't cause an issue in the browser.. This `$comment;"</div>"` also should be `$comment . "</div>"`

Comment: can't see how this code would add ANY spaces in there. have you tried "silly" things, like ripping out the html inside the echo entirely and outputting the just the variable? start tracking down where the space comes from by eliminating other things.

Comment: Your code doesn't produce what you claim it produces when I run it on any of my computers. Please fix any typos (mainly, the ; after $comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$comment = "Enabled";  // add comment, whenever this value is not set to "0"

            <td>
^^^^^^^^^^^^ 12
```

See here:

```
Enabled            </div>
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ 12
```

It's caused by the **12** spaces up there (I counted them). Plus, since you did not show your actual code as to where you closed your `?>` tag, that will also contribute to it.

Therefore and as an example:

```
<?php
    $comment = "Enabled";  // add comment, whenever this value is not set to "0"
?><td>
```

However, the following is off. The semi-colon's in the wrong spot and is missing a dot to concatenate:

```
<?= !$comment ? "" : "<div class=\"design\">Comment: " . $comment . "</div>"; ?>
```

So, avoid any spaces after closing `?>` tags or before `<?php`. PHP's adding spaces for it and look at your HTML source; it's just as good a developer tool as any.

Answer (score 0):

remove semicolon ";" and replace with dot "." in

```
 ". $comment;"</div>" ?>
```