# PHP echo when empty doesn't work

Tags: php

I'm trying to hide a table row whenever `$visible` is not empty:

```
<?php
$visible = "yes";  // hide the row if different than "0"
?>
<HTML>
//Big HTML Block
<tr<?= !$visible ? "" : "class=\"hidden\""; ?>>
```

but my output is:

`<tr>`

instead of:

`<tr class="hidden">`

What's wrong? and is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do here?
I do it this way basically since I want to define right at the top of the code, whether that `<TR>` that comes after a lot of HTML code, will be visible or not. It's a sort of a template that I'm creating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"yes"` is a string, not a boolean value. So as long as the string isn't empty (or the special case `"0"`), php interprets this as `true`. And so `!$visible` = `!true` = `false`. So the second branch in the ternary condition is chosen. In any case, your logic appears to be backwards. Try using boolean `true` in place of the string `"yes"` and remove the `!`.

```
<?php
$visible = true;
?>
<HTML>
//Big HTML Block
<tr<?= $visible ? "" : " class=\"hidden\""; ?>>
```

Comment: if it stems from being a string, why did it work for me [in this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795326/unwanted-space-when-echoing-a-value/34795576)? Also, I tried your method and it still doesn't work..

Comment: The primary reason the results seem backwards is because of the misplaced `!`. Using a string for a true/false/yes/no/on/off type variable instead of a boolean just confuses the issue. If you coded it up such that `"yes"` produces the desired result, one might reasonably expect that `"no"` produced the opposite result but it won't work because both `"yes"` and `"no"` evaluate to boolean `true` when used in conditionals. Eliminate confusion and use a boolean instead.

Comment: @rockyraw. I just tested my code. Toggling `$visible` between `true` and `false` produces `<tr>` and `<tr class="hidden">`, respectively. Are you sure you're testing the right block of code?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $visible = true;  // hide the row if different than "0"
    ?>
    <HTML>
    //Big HTML Block
    <tr<?php if($visible)
    echo "class=\"hidden\"";
    else
    echo ""; ?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if it is "yes"

```
<?= $visible == "yes" ? "show" : "" ?>
```

Or set the value to an boolean like

```
$visible = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning, but I find evaluating a conditional is easier to read if you write without the !condition. Also, use "" around '' rather than escaping each quote.  Try that code, I may be missing something.

```
    <?php
        $invisible = true;  // hide the row if different than "0"
    ?>

    <tr class="<?= $invisible ? 'hidden' : ''; ?>">
       #stuff
    </tr>
```